# Where are my comments

Tags: feature-request

I do get notified on Answers and comments (if addressed to me), but since I am quite active over multiple sites, how about been notified on all follow up comments in the OP or Answers where I gave a comment.

Some users do not use the @ to address me directly, but I would like to see they comment following my comment.

I would like to know if there is a way to see all comments I made, or even better to be notified when a comment is made after my comment.

Something like "Track" would be a nice option to have.

Sorry if duplicate, but I spend some time looking for already asked but could not find it.

Answer (score 3):

You **can** see all your comments:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/46541/buscar?tab=activity&sort=comments

Also, if you comment on a question/answer and the poster of that question/answer comments after you, then you will be notified even if the poster does not @-tag you.